# An error occurs when trying to set a child to my GameObject in script

Tags: c#, error-handling, unity-game-engine, monodevelop, gameobject

```
GameObject enemy = Instantiate(spawnObject,spawnPosition,spawnObject.transform.rotation) as GameObject;
enemy.transform.parent = transform;
```

The above code generates the expected result when I test my game in game mode, however I'm gettting this error message:

"Setting the parent of a transform which resides in a prefab is disabled to prevent data corruption."

Yes, the spawnObject variable contains a prefab, however creating a new GameObject should have fixed the problem, I assume?

Answer (score 2):

Check if your "transform" variable is actually from a gameobject and not from a prefab.

```
var transform = somePrefab.transform;
enemy.transform.parent = transform; // this won't work

var transform = someOtherGameObject.transform;
enemy.transform.parent = transform; // this will
```

Maybe you could give some more information about where that transform variable of yours comes from.

Answer (score 0):

I've been seeing this issue as well - an instantiated GameObject (not the prefab) giving this error message.  My GameObject (A) had been parented into the middle of another instantiated GameObject (B) of a different type.  I wanted to reparent A into another part of B - which would fail with the given error.  My only solution has been to first reparent A to null, then reparent into B again.