# Unity Error: Setting the parent of a transform which resides in a Prefab Asset is disabled to prevent data corruption

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to instantiate the following object to a child of the `gameobject` this script resides:

```
 var newEnergyPart = Instantiate<GameObject>(energyPart, energyBarLayout.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
           newEnergyPart.transform.SetParent(energyBarLayout.gameObject.transform);
```

However, It keeps giving me this error:

> Setting the parent of a transform which resides in a Prefab Asset is disabled to prevent data corruption (GameObject: 'BarUnit(Clone)').
>   UnityEngine.Transform:SetParent(Transform)

I thought that making sure to set parent to an object set as n instantiated `gameobject` would make the error go aways it keeps appearing.

Comment: Include more of your code. Is `energyBarLayout` a prefab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- It looks like 'energyBarLayout' script attached to Prefab object, you cannot set 'Prefab' as parent of instantiated transform so should check and change 'energyBarLayout'.
- In your case, you tried to create 'newEnergyPart' before instantiate parent object so I think you should instantiate 'energyBarLayout' GameObject first and then create 'newEnergyPart' so It would work definitely.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14371903/an-error-occurs-when-trying-to-set-a-child-to-my-gameobject-in-script?rq=1